# How to use Mobx for local store, passing store to components

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

Instead of injecting a store at the top level of the app using Provider, is there a way to use a store class locally at the component level?

For example -- I have a class/store which is used to build an HTML table. But each table is different, which is why I don't want to inject it at the top level. I want each page that has an HTML table to have it's own store instance, and feed it the properties. That way I can run ajax queries and insert the result into the store.

Is this possible?

Comment: I would use the `local state` of the component instead. Prefer to use global stores if they have significance in other components too. I makes debugging easier and logic clean

Comment: @uneet7 Thanks but I did find a solution. One way is to export the class definition and simply import it into the component and then create a new instance. As long as the component which uses it is wrapped in an observer it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to export the class definition and simply import it into the component which will use it and then create a new instance. As long as the component which uses it is wrapped in an observer it works just fine.